# Cordova js library methods not working on iOS but works on Android

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, payment-gateway

Currently im integrating a payment gateway which uses their [library](https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/static/checkout/checkout.js)
[integration guide](https://test-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html?locale=en_US#x_setupHCO)

However, while calling the Checkout.showEmbeddedPage function from the library, it gets stuck for ios, but it works fine on Android. There are no console logs nor network logs when its stuck, it just keeps loading.

Seems like this is a cordova issue because i'm getting response from the safari browser but not on the app itself. I'm not sure whether is it some webview problem.

```
        Checkout.configure({
          order: {
            description: output.description,
            id: output.orderId
          },
          session: {
            id: output.session.id,
            version: output.session.version
          },
          interaction: {
            displayControl: {
              billingAddress: 'HIDE',
              shipping: 'HIDE',
            },
            merchant: {
              name: output.merchant,
            },
          }
        });
        Checkout.showEmbeddedPage('#embedded_page');
```

I've tried by adding
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src * data: https:;  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>`
to the index.html file but still not working for ios (index.html is where i call the library)